# Get JSON object keys as array in Presto/Trino

Tags: sql, presto, jsonpath, trino

I have JSON data like this in one of my columns

```
{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
{"foo": 1}
```

and I would like to run a query that returns the keys as an array

```
foo,bar
foo
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert your JSON into a `MAP` and then use [`map_keys()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html?highlight=map_keys#map_keys):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(js) as (
    VALUES (JSON '{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}'),
        (JSON '{"foo": 1}')
)

-- query
SELECT array_join(map_keys(CAST(js AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))),  ', ')
FROM dataset
```

Use `json_parse()` if your JSON column is of type `VARCHAR`

```sql
SELECT array_join(map_keys(CAST(json_parse(js) AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))),  ', ')
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| bar, foo |
| foo |

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to work well with JSON, but if we convert the JSON to a MAP, the process is simple using `map_values`:

```sql
WITH data as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES JSON '{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}', JSON '{"foo": 1}') AS t(json_col))

SELECT map_values(CAST(json_col AS MAP(VARCHAR, INTEGER))) json_col
FROM data
```

Output:

| json_col |
| --- |
| {2,1} |
| {1} |

Comment: I needed the keys, not the values, but thank you for your answer